How to change feedzy rss plugin cache time in wordpress
https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedzy-rss-feeds/
In this plugin, is the minimum cache time 1h but I need to change it to 1 min.
I need it because my news are time critical and need to be load fastly.
Does anybody can help me with that?
Hopefully somebody can send me working code with some explanation.

If you still need it...
You can manage all the cron jobs, including Feedzy's, of your Wordpress site  with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/
